# User theming (control positioning) in win forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm looking to allow users to position existing controls via a theme file.

For instance, imagine if there was a text box at the top middle, a picture bottom left and a button at the bottom right.

The user would be able to specify the positions of the elements via a theme file.

I'm not asking how to create a theme file. My intent is to gather if this is possible first using win forms and how others go about it.

I know that it's possible using WPF and xaml, but I'd prefer to use win forms and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing to XAML UI like WPF, which is *layout-based*, WinForms is *coordinate-based* framework, so, if you load control's location from somewhere, you can easily apply it. Something like this:

```
var userNameTextBox.Location = myThemeService.LoadLocation(userNameTextBox.Name);
```

Note, that [`Location`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location(v=vs.110).aspx) is relative to control's container.
You have to consider this when setting coordinates in your theme.

Comment: Very interesting! I'm new to C# and win forms so this is really useful. This should suffice for my needs.